# NSAttributedString with dynamic ranges

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have to format a string with 3 styles. The string is something like:

```
1.0000 of 2.000
```

`1.0000` has a foreground red color, `of` has a smaller font and `2.000` has to be green.

The problem is that the numbers could be in any range, so the first and the second numbers could be composed by 4,5,6 whatever chars.

How can I perform formatting of a string like that?

Edit-----------------
I add some more info: the string maintains its format. So for example this could be its template: `N of N`

Comment: A little more information would be helpful, like is the string similar in, like xxxxx of yyyyy, or the 'words' might be different.

Comment: I've added some info about the string format.

Answer (score 5):

Lets suppose you have these three :

```
NSString *string0 = @"1.0000"; NSString *string1 = @"of"; NSString
*string2 = @"2.000";


NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",
                          string0 ,string1,string2];

        //whole String attribute
        NSDictionary *attribs = @{
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                  NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]
                                  };

        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attribs];

        NSRange string0Range = [text rangeOfString:string0];
        NSRange string1Range = [text rangeOfString:string1];
        NSRange string2Range = [text rangeOfString:string2];
        [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]  range:string0Range];
         [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]  range:string1Range]; [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]  range:string2Range];
        [yourLabel setAttributedText:attributedText];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use NSScanner or NSRegularExpression to find the numeric expression and its pieces.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be :

```
NSString* myString = @"12.345 of 56.789";

NSMutableAttributedString * tempString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString];

NSRange midrange = [tempString.string rangeOfString:@"of"];



[tempString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.6],
                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]}
                    range:NSMakeRange(0, midrange.location)];

[tempString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.6],
                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}
                    range:midrange];

[tempString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.6],
                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor]}
                    range:NSMakeRange(midrange.location + midrange.length, tempString.length - midrange.location - midrange.length)];

yourElement.attributedText = tempString;
```

[image]